# unwrapping optionals in swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I am still trying to wrap my head around optionals in swift. Can someone explain why when we created the model object we put an '!' after and also when creating the quizCountries array of strings we also put the '!' and set it equal to nil. I don't really understand why we would want something to ever be nil in the program.

```
//  QuizViewController.swift
import UIKit

class QuizViewController: UIViewController, ModelDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var flagImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var segmentedControls: [UISegmentedControl]!

    private var model: Model! // reference to the model object
    private let correctColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    private let incorrectColor = UIColor.redColor()
    private var quizCountries: [String]! = nil // countries in quiz
    private var enabledCountries: [String]! = nil // countries for guesses
    private var correctAnswer: String! = nil
    private var correctGuesses = 0
    private var totalGuesses = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create IBOutlets by dragging from elements in interface builder to the source file they default to being Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals (IUOs) with `!`'s. You can manually change the them to be proper optionals with `?` so that you can handle them carefully and let the compiler check all the cases.

You might be interested in the cases when they could be `nil`. These are a few that I have thought of although I may have missed some.

1. Before the view loads (before `viewDidLoad` has been called) they will be nil.
2. If you ever explicitly set them to `nil`.
3. If the item has been removed from Interface Builder.
4. If the outlet has been removed from Interface Builder.
5. If you have multiple views/view controllers in Interface Builder which use the same class and one has the outlets connected and another doesn't.
6. If you have two Storyboards (e.g. one for iPhone and one for iPad) that both reference the same class but only one has the IBOutlet connected.
7. If you ever unload the view the outlets are likely to become nil again.

Given all these possibilities I prefer to use proper optionals. I blogged about [how I deal with optionals](http://blog.human-friendly.com/how-i-handle-optionals-in-swift) and also [gave a talk](http://blog.human-friendly.com/beyond-if-let) on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Exclamation mark after the property name indicates that this is an *implicitly unwrapped optional*.

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter. The primary use of implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift is during class initialization, as described in [Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID55).

These are useful when referenced object, e.g. `model` in your case, is not yet known at the moment of initialisation of `QuizViewController` but still is guaranteed to be available and assigned to the `model` property before its first use.  Same goes for `quizCountries`, we do not know these countries yet when the controller is created but will certainly know them before they are going to be used.

In case if implicitly unwrapped optional, contrary to expectation, is (still) `nil` at the moment of its use the application will crash.